# Windows 10 IoT Core, Builtin WIFI

Tags: wifi, pi-3, windows-iot

I am wondering if anyone has figured out how to get the *built-in wifi* working on the **Raspberry Pi 3, Model B** with **Windows 10 IoT Core**? Is there a driver floating around somewhere or know what specific preview build I should target?

Supposedly, someone [claims that](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/29/windows-10-iot-core-support-for-raspberry-pi-3/) `build 14322` has it working...

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 IoT Core (Insider Preview) - Build 14376 (Free - 32 bits): support on-board WiFi, and on-board Bluetooth.